# Hyperlinked cell to to show results on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have two worksheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 has a list like shown below:

```
 Col1
 A1A
 A2A
 A2C
 A4A
 A4B
```

and sheet2 has a formula on cell b2 that does an index and match function. Am fairly new to excel and was wondering can I make the Col1 in Sheet1 into hyperlinks so that anytime I click on an item on Col1 (lets say A1A), it takes me to Sheet2 and the Cell B2 on sheet2 gets populated with the clicked hyperlink?

Comment: There's a good explanation of how to do this [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/15/excel-insert-hyperlink/)

Comment: @PeterT. I read the article and it talks about creating a hyperlink in the existing worksheet. I used that to create hyperlinks. But when I click on the link it should populate the Cell B2 in Sheet2 with the clicked item in Sheet1. That's where am getting lost at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried a sheet module selection change? ie.,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Target.Value = "A1A" Or Target.Row = 1 Then
        Sheet2.Range("B" & Target.Row) = Target.Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. No, I haven't tried it. Am not too well versed with VBA and was wondering if there's a formula to do it. How does this work and which worksheet do I add this to?

Comment: This would be on the worksheet module of the worksheet containing the list "A1A", "A2A", "A2C", etc in column A.  I set the "If" for either the value of the changed cell or the row of "A1A" - so if a user puts "A1A" into column 1 row1, then it automatically puts "A1A" into Sheet2.range("B1").  However you could change the range to anything you like.  You'd have to modify it to fit your particular needs.  My computer doesn't download images and I'm not very good with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

With acknowledgement to the [AbleBits](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/15/excel-insert-hyperlink/) site, make sure you note a couple things in the process.

For this example I want cell C3 on Sheet2 to point back to cell A1 on Sheet1. So, I have this formula in `Sheet2!C3`:

[image]

Then on `Sheet1`, in `Cell A1`, I right-clicked to pull up the menu then selected `Hyperlink...`. Make sure of three things:

1. Choose `Place in This Document`
2. Choose the correct sheet to reference (`Sheet2`)
3. Choose the correct cell to refernece (`cell C3`)
4. Optionally change the `Text to display` at the top of the dialog.

[image]

With all that, you get the following on `Sheet1`:

[image]

So when you click the link in cell A1 on Sheet1, you get sent back to Sheet2 and it shows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If I have long list of items that need to be hyperlinked to the same cell reference on sheet 1. Would this still work? For example, if I have a long list of items in Col1, sheet 1 of my example, can I hyperlink all of the items to the same point? if so, can I do it in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Follow_Hyperlink event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838843.aspx) which has range called Target as a parameter, which is the cell containing the hyperlink. Use the range to set up your logic e.g:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
     Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
     Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address) = whatever you want in B4 on sheet 2
End if
```